# Error "pattern did not match any bands"

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, normalized-difference-water-index

I'm a GIS Student and I'm learning how to use Google Earth Engine. I'm trying to make a GEE APP in which through a dropdown menu I select an index (in this case NDWI_Veg or NDWI_Water) and it shows on the map. This is made for a single image "LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT_TOA/LC08_219077_20200531".

I've followed this great tutorial about "Publishing an Earth Engine App to Accompany your Research Paper" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saaecbImPmI) which helped me to create the grounds to work with.

I've tried to modify the code of the video and I'm getting the error

> "NDWI_VEG: Layer error: Image.select: Pattern 'NDWI_VEG' did not match
> any bands."

I'm not quite sure how to correct this. The code is as follows:

```
var m = {};

m.img = ee.Image("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT_TOA/LC08_219077_20200531")

var NDWI_Veg = m.img.expression(
  '(nir-swir )/(nir + swir )',
  {
    swir: m.img.select('B6'),  
    nir: m.img.select('B5'),  
  } ).rename('NDWI_VEG');
  
var NDWI_Water = m.img.expression(
  '(green-nir )/(green + nir )',
  {
    green: m.img.select('B3'),  
    nir: m.img.select('B5'),  
  } ).rename('NDWI_WATER');
  

m.imgInfo = {
  bands:{
    'NDWI_VEG':{
      bname: 'NDWI_VEG',
      color: 'd4e7b0',
      vis: {
        min: -1,
        max: 1,
      }
    },
    'NDWI_WATER': {
      bname: 'NDWI_WATER',
      color: 'd2cdc0',
      vis: {
        min: -1,
        max: 1,
      }
    },
    }
};


var c = {};

c.controlPanel = ui.Panel();
c.map = ui.Map();

c.info = {};

c.info.titleLabel = ui.Label('Placeholder Title');
c.info.aboutLabel = ui.Label(
  'Placeholder About');
c.info.panel = ui.Panel([
  c.info.titleLabel, c.info.aboutLabel
  ]);


c.selectBand = {};
c.selectBand.label = ui.Label('Select a band to display');
c.selectBand.selector = ui.Select(Object.keys(m.imgInfo.bands), null, 'NDWI_VEG'); 
c.selectBand.panel = ui.Panel([c.selectBand.label, c.selectBand.selector]);

c.dividers = {};
c.dividers.divider1 = ui.Panel()
c.dividers.divider2 = ui.Panel()


ui.root.clear();
ui.root.add(c.controlPanel);
ui.root.add(c.map);

c.controlPanel.add(c.info.panel);
c.controlPanel.add(c.dividers.divider2);
c.controlPanel.add(c.selectBand.panel);

var s = {};

s.aboutText = {
  fontSize: '13px',
  color: '505050'
};

s.widgetTitle = {
  fontSize: '15px',
  fontWeight:'bold',
  margin: '8px 8px 0px 8px',
  color: '383838'
};

s.stretchHorizontal = {
  stretch: 'horizontal'
};

s.divider = {
  backgroundColor: 'F0F0F0',
  height: '4px',
  margin: '20px 0px'
};

c.controlPanel.style().set({
  width: '275px'
});

c.info.titleLabel.style().set({
  fontSize: '20px',
  fontWeight: 'bold'
});

c.info.aboutLabel.style().set(s.aboutText);

c.selectBand.label.style().set(s.widgetTitle);
c.selectBand.selector.style().set(s.stretchHorizontal);

Object.keys(c.dividers).forEach(function(key){
  c.dividers[key].style().set(s.divider);
  }
);

function updateMap(){
  var band = c.selectBand.selector.getValue();
  
  var img = m.img.select(m.imgInfo.bands[band].bname);
    
  var layer = ui.Map.Layer({
    eeObject: img,
    visParams: m.imgInfo.bands[band].vis,
    name: band
  });
  c.map.layers().set(0,layer);
}

c.selectBand.selector.onChange(updateMap);

updateMap()
```

I'm still learning how to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is indicating that the 'NDWI_VEG' band is not in the image you are calling. Thus, you just need to add the NDWI bands to the original image. Add the following line, after creating both `NDWI_Veg` and `NDWI_Water` images.

```
m.img = m.img.addBands(NDWI_Veg.addBands(NDWI_Water));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! God bless your work!